# Calculate mean for subgroup within group

Tags: r, mean

I would like to calculate the mean for a subgroup within a group. Data looks like this

| sex | season | outcome |
| --- | --- | --- |
| F | breed | 0 |
| F | breed | 0 |
| F | breed | 1 |
| F | breed | 1 |
| F | breed | 1 |
| F | breed | 0 |
| F | breed | 0 |
| F | molt | 0 |
| F | molt | 1 |
| F | molt | 1 |
| F | winter | 1 |
| F | winter | 0 |
| F | breed | 0 |
| F | breed | 0 |
| F | breed | 1 |
| F | breed | 1 |
| M | breed | 0 |
| M | breed | 0 |
| M | breed | 0 |
| M | molt | 0 |
| M | molt | 1 |
| M | molt | 1 |
| M | winter | 0 |
| M | winter | 0 |

I would like to calculate the mean of the outcome for each sex within season. For example, I would like to know the mean of the outcome for females during the breeding, molting, and winter season. I would like to repeat this for males.

I can calculate the mean of the outcome per sex using this code:

```
detect %>% 
    group_by(sex) %>% 
   summarise(dr = mean(outcome))
```

But I do not know how to break things down into the subgroup of seasons.

Comment: Simply  try `group_by(sex, season)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track. Just add the second column you want to group with, as Park's mentioned in the comments section, just instead of `season` use `breed` (assuming I properly understand your need):

```r
detect %>% 
  group_by(sex, breed) %>% 
  summarise(dr = mean(outcome))
```